Invoke-Command is failing in combination with PackageProvider commands
I am trying to install nuget package provider by using:
Find-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -ForceBootsrap -IncludeDependencies in combination with Invoke-command -session $mysession
But when running it from Invoke-command with session: I am getting the classic error with:
WARNING: Unable to download from URI 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/
         ?LinkID=627338&clcid=0x409' to ''.
WARNING: Unable to download the list of available providers. Check your internet
         connection.

But if I am doing a RDP to my VM and running the same command is working, what is different when running with Invoke-Command?
User account using in session is administrator.
I tried already all configurations with tls12.
I am expecting:
Install nuget package provider with invoke-command

It sounds like the double hop issue but I wouldn’t have thought a web call would be subject to it. Maybe the command needs to call AD for permissions, that would definitely be a double hop. Does this same command work to a dc? That could confirm

What is a dc?
Another interesting fact is when using invoke-webrequest for downloading that nuget DLL, I am getting this error: Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. But when I am checking the internet connection, ipv4 is running and receiving data.

Dc = domain controller

I checked connection to DC and is working fine. I used nltest /dsgetdc and Test-ComputerSecureChannel, bot checks ar fine.

You misunderstand my suggestion. I was trying to help you rule out double hop issue, not test domain services.

Indeed. Now I got it, I tried running Import-Module ActiveDirectory and Get-AdUser but both commands returned: Unable to contact the server. This may be because this server does not exist, it is currently down, or it does not have Active Directory web services running. Did exactly the same commands directly on VM and is working. I tried one more think, trying Register-PSSessionConfiguration but it failed with: Failed to refresh. Message: ‘Unable to find type [Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.Article] and the session will be broken

By default you can’t query AD over Invoke-Command because of the double hop issue. My suggestion was to try your original commands but against a domain controller instead of a workstation or member server.

But is a curl request falling in double hop issue? I thought this is happening only when you are in a pssession in server1 and then from server1 you want to connect to server2.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

That’s what I’ve said already, I wouldn’t expect the web request to hit a double hop. But think about what you are doing, trying to install stuff with the forcebootstrap. Now if that action required a permission  check on a user or a group membership, then that could be the second hop. Either try your original commands AGAINST a dc or try removing the forcebootstrap so it’s just a package lookup

For the record I don’t think that’s the issue, it’s just the issue makes no sense. I’m just trying to help you rule out the double hop

I tried without -forcebootstrap but same issue only that is prompting for yes or no. Meanwhile in order to fix it I did an workaround, download that DLL manually store it in an internal storage and install it from there. But still is interesting knowing why this is not working.
